# Sqlite Query Help

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I have one table table1 and another table table2. Both has same column name say "description". table1 has some data in description column and table2 has no(null) data. So how can i update data from table1 into table2 description column ?.They have one column which has same values in both and unique too. any idea?

Comment: What other columns are in the tables? Do the descriptions you're adding to table2 need to be linked to specific id in the table?

Comment: Yes there is one id in both tables which are same and having unique values.I edited my question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work provided the key is Unique:

```
UPDATE db2.table2 SET description = (SELECT table1.description FROM db1.table1 AS table1 WHERE table1.id = db1.table2.id)
```

Comment: I am giving alias name to both tables,but it is showing error.Is there any prohibition in giving alias name in case of update.

Comment: @Android Power: You cannot give an alias to the table you're updating in an UPDATE. Refer to it using its own name, and if you need the same table in sub-selects then use aliases there.

Comment: My problem is that both tables in 2 different database.I am updating table but it is throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update t1 set b=(select b from t2 where a=t1.a);
```

where `b` is the description and `a` is the matching value.